# Replace the angularjs pop-up and change to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Hi I am in kind of unique situation. We have a code in angularjs and I have given a task to join it with a html in jquery. This jquery page opens when we click on 
a particular link. I checked the code and find out it calls **ModalService.showModal**  and it is passing two name. One is the template and one is the controller name.
Now, what I have done is I checked where this function defination is. There I commented out that if controller name is empty then also go forward.

The function is this-

```
self.showModal = function(options) {

        //  Create a deferred we'll resolve when the modal is ready.
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        //  Validate the input parameters.
        var controllerName = options.controller;
        if (!controllerName) {
          //deferred.reject("No controller has been specified.");
          //return deferred.promise;
        }
```

But if I do this nothing is happening. How we can do this. Please anyone help me on this.

EDIT:
I have page in angularjs and html. Now there is link in that page which is just a pop-up. Now, I want to change the pop-up to a jquery pop-up. 
But I dont know how to add it. 
Here is the link from where I have to call jquery table but it has controller what do I pass from it.

Here is the function of link in the controller

```
//  link click
    $scope.Inventary = function () {
        if ($scope.Inmdata1 != "") {
            ModalService.showModal({
                templateUrl: "ChartpagePopup/Details.html",
                controller: "Details"
            }).then(function (modal) {
                modal.close.then(function (result) {

                });
            });
        }
        else
            alert($scope.waitingalert);
    };
```

Comment: What does "User jquey in angular js" mean ?

Comment: Sorry changed the title it was spelling mistake

Comment: wheres the jQuery? Theres none in your code

Comment: I do not understand which is the issue and the desired behaviour

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I did not include jquery. I want to know where I should change so that the link should work

Comment: what link? Your question is so unclear as to be unanswerable in its current state

Comment: Specifically `have given a task to join it with a html in jquery` - what does this mean? `This jquery page opens when we click on a particular link` - what is a "jQuery page"?

Comment: I have add the code for link in controller. Now here instead of that link I want my jquery page to be open. I have not developed both angular nor jquey but I have given task to join these both

Comment: I think the OP is facing problems with framing his question, although he did try to update his question to make it more explanatory, I am still finding it difficult to understand his question. This looks like an issue because of language barrier, if anyone understood his question, then please help him edit the question.

Comment: @FlyingGambit I have page in angularjs and html. Now there is link in that page which is just a pop-up. Now, I want to change the pop-up to a jquery pop-up. But I don't have a controller so what do I do.